# Getting timestamp from one column and put it in another one with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm using watchdog to monitor some folders and create a csv file to see when a file is created and modified. Now, I got a dataframe like this from the csv:

```
       full_path             name             created           modified
0    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt            14:04:30             NaN
1    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt              NaN              14:04:30
2    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt            14:10:30              NaN
3    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt              NaN              14:10:30
4    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt            14:15:30             NaN
5    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt              NaN              14:15:30
6    C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt   1.txt            14:20:30             NaN
7    C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt   1.txt              NaN              14:20:30
8    C:\T1\2.txt            2.txt            14:25:30             NaN
9    C:\T1\2.txt            2.txt              NaN              14:25:30
10   C:\T1\T2\2.txt         2.txt            14:30:30             NaN
11   C:\T1\T2\2.txt         2.txt              NaN              14:30:30
12   C:\T1\T2\T3\2.txt      2.txt            14:35:30             NaN
13   C:\T1\T2\T3\2.txt      2.txt              NaN              14:35:30
14   C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\2.txt   2.txt              NaN              14:40:30
```

Watchdog, usually gives two timestamps when a file is moved to another folder (created and modified), but somehow for the last file when it moved to T4 folder it gave only the modified timestamp. I use this code to convert this dataframe in only two rows and I put the timestamps for each folder in other columns:

```
m0 = (df["full_path"].ne(df["full_path"].shift(1, fill_value=df["full_path"].iloc[0])) & df["name"].eq(df["name"].shift(fill_value=df["name"].iloc[0])))
m1 = df["full_path"].eq(df.loc[df["full_path"].str.rsplit("\\", 2).str[-2] == 'T1', 'full_path'])
m2 = df["full_path"].eq(df.loc[df["full_path"].str.rsplit("\\", 2).str[-2] == 'T2', 'full_path'])
m3 = df["full_path"].eq(df.loc[df["full_path"].str.rsplit("\\", 2).str[-2] == 'T3', 'full_path'])
m4 = df["full_path"].eq(df.loc[df["full_path"].str.rsplit("\\", 2).str[-2] == 'T4', 'full_path'])

df['T1'] = np.where(m0 & m1, df['created'], "")
df['T2'] = np.where(m0 & m2, df['created'], "")
df['T3'] = np.where(m0 & m3, df['created'], "")
df['T4'] = np.where(m0 & m4, df['created'], "")

df = df.groupby(['name'], sort=False).agg({'full_path':'last','created':'first', 'modified':'last','T1':'first', 'T2':lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)), 'T3':lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)), 'T4':'last'}).reset_index()
```

And it gives me a dataframe like this one:

```
   full_path             name   created    modified      T1       T2        T3          T4
0  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt  1.txt  14:04:30   14:20:30  14:04:30   14:10:30  14:15:30   14:20:30  
1  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\2.txt  2.txt  14:25:30   14:40:30  14:25:30   14:30:30  14:35:30      NaN
```

How can I modify my code to detect for example for the file 2.txt when it moved to folder T4, if the "created" column in NaN, get the timestamp from the "modified" column, and have a dataframe like this one:

```
   full_path             name   created    modified      T1       T2        T3          T4
0  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt  1.txt  14:04:30   14:20:30  14:04:30   14:10:30  14:15:30   14:20:30  
1  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\2.txt  2.txt  14:25:30   14:40:30  14:25:30   14:30:30  14:35:30   14:40:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer the specific question. Use `fillna` and pass in the values from 'modified' before the `groupby` which will fill the NaN values in T4 with values from modified:

```
df['T4'] = df['T4'].fillna(df['modified'])
```

---

As an alternative maybe use something like pathlib to get the name of the parent folder.

#### Imports

```
from pathlib import PurePath

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

#### Sample Frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'full_path': {0: 'C:\\T1\\1.txt', 1: 'C:\\T1\\1.txt',
                  2: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\1.txt', 3: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\1.txt',
                  4: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\1.txt',
                  5: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\1.txt',
                  6: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\T4\\1.txt',
                  7: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\T4\\1.txt',
                  8: 'C:\\T1\\2.txt', 9: 'C:\\T1\\2.txt',
                  10: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\2.txt',
                  11: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\2.txt',
                  12: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\2.txt',
                  13: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\2.txt',
                  14: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\T4\\2.txt'},
    'name': {0: '1.txt', 1: '1.txt', 2: '1.txt', 3: '1.txt',
             4: '1.txt', 5: '1.txt', 6: '1.txt', 7: '1.txt',
             8: '2.txt', 9: '2.txt', 10: '2.txt', 11: '2.txt',
             12: '2.txt', 13: '2.txt', 14: '2.txt'},
    'created': {0: '14:04:30', 1: np.nan, 2: '14:10:30', 3: np.nan,
                4: '14:15:30', 5: np.nan, 6: '14:20:30', 7: np.nan,
                8: '14:25:30', 9: np.nan, 10: '14:30:30', 11: np.nan,
                12: '14:35:30', 13: np.nan, 14: np.nan},
    'modified': {0: np.nan, 1: '14:04:30', 2: np.nan, 3: '14:10:30',
                 4: np.nan, 5: '14:15:30', 6: np.nan, 7: '14:20:30',
                 8: np.nan, 9: '14:25:30', 10: np.nan, 11: '14:30:30',
                 12: np.nan, 13: '14:35:30', 14: '14:40:30'}
})
```

#### Get Folder Names

```
# Get Parent Folder Name From Each Path
df['folder'] = df['full_path'].apply(lambda x: PurePath(x).parent.name)
print(df.to_string())
```

```
               full_path   name   created  modified folder
0            C:\T1\1.txt  1.txt  14:04:30       NaN     T1
1            C:\T1\1.txt  1.txt       NaN  14:04:30     T1
2         C:\T1\T2\1.txt  1.txt  14:10:30       NaN     T2
3         C:\T1\T2\1.txt  1.txt       NaN  14:10:30     T2
4      C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt  1.txt  14:15:30       NaN     T3
5      C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt  1.txt       NaN  14:15:30     T3
6   C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt  1.txt  14:20:30       NaN     T4
7   C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt  1.txt       NaN  14:20:30     T4
8            C:\T1\2.txt  2.txt  14:25:30       NaN     T1
9            C:\T1\2.txt  2.txt       NaN  14:25:30     T1
10        C:\T1\T2\2.txt  2.txt  14:30:30       NaN     T2
11        C:\T1\T2\2.txt  2.txt       NaN  14:30:30     T2
12     C:\T1\T2\T3\2.txt  2.txt  14:35:30       NaN     T3
13     C:\T1\T2\T3\2.txt  2.txt       NaN  14:35:30     T3
14  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\2.txt  2.txt       NaN  14:40:30     T4
```

Then the end result can be more easily accomplished:

```
# Get Parent Folder Name From Each Path
df['folder'] = df['full_path'].apply(lambda x: PurePath(x).parent.name)
# Keep Groupby Name handy for later
g = df.groupby('name')
# Transform each group to be the last path
df['full_path'] = g['full_path'].transform('last')
# combine_first created with modified (new column to not affect data)
df['c_m'] = df['created'].combine_first(df['modified'])

index_cols = ['full_path', 'name']
# Pivot to wide format
df = df.pivot_table(index=index_cols,
                    columns='folder',
                    values='c_m',
                    aggfunc='first')

# Add Summary Columns
summary_cols = ['created', 'modified']
# Merge on name
df = df.reset_index() \
    .merge(g[summary_cols].agg({'created': 'first', 'modified': 'last'}),
           on='name')

# Re-order Columns and axis names
df = df[[*index_cols,
         *summary_cols,
         *df.columns.difference(summary_cols + index_cols)]] \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

# Output
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

`df`:

```
           full_path  name  created modified       T1       T2       T3       T4
C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt 1.txt 14:04:30 14:20:30 14:04:30 14:10:30 14:15:30 14:20:30
C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\2.txt 2.txt 14:25:30 14:40:30 14:25:30 14:30:30 14:35:30 14:40:30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @henryecker for the answer. Also your alternative is much better. I'm going to use it  instead of mine.

Comment: Hey @henryecker, My real dataframe is much bigger with different file names on it. With your solution when I do df.pivot_table(), the files are sorted alphabetically and then when we say df[summary_cols] = g[summary_cols .agg({'created': 'first', 'modified': 'last'}).to_numpy(). It is mixing "created" and "modified" timestamps with other files. Can we do pivot_table without sorting it alphabetically?

Comment: I updated the answer. I think doing a merge on `name` is probably a better approach than trying to match the sorting. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hey @henryecker, yes now it is working perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey@henryecker, if for example file 1.txt after some time is moved back to T3, is there a possible way to remove the time stamp in T4?

Comment: Hi @user14073111 most likely, however, it's going to be difficult to get all the specific information necessary to solve that kind of problem over the comments. I think you're going to have better results asking a _new_ question so that you can fully explain the conditions and provide sample data and sample outputs.

Comment: [already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210179/delete-a-value-in-a-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column-with-pandas), can you check it please?