# Delete a value in a column based on the value of another column with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

Lets say I have a dataframe like this

```
       full_path             name             created           modified
0    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt            14:04:30             NaN
1    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt              NaN              14:04:30
2    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt            14:10:30              NaN
3    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt              NaN              14:10:30
4    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt            14:15:30             NaN
5    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt              NaN              14:15:30
6    C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt   1.txt            14:20:30             NaN
```

I use this code to create a dataframe:

```
from pathlib import PurePath
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'full_path': {0: 'C:\\T1\\1.txt', 1: 'C:\\T1\\1.txt',
                  2: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\1.txt', 3: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\1.txt',
                  4: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\1.txt',
                  5: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\1.txt',
                  6: 'C:\\T1\\T2\\T3\\T4\\1.txt'},
    'name': {0: '1.txt', 1: '1.txt', 2: '1.txt', 3: '1.txt',
             4: '1.txt', 5: '1.txt', 6: '1.txt'},
    'created': {0: '14:04:30', 1: np.nan, 2: '14:10:30', 3: np.nan,
                4: '14:15:30', 5: np.nan, 6: '14:20:30'},
    'modified': {0: np.nan, 1: '14:04:30', 2: np.nan, 3: '14:10:30',
                 4: np.nan, 5: '14:15:30', 6: np.nan}
})

df['folder'] = df['full_path'].apply(lambda x: PurePath(x).parent.name)
g = df.groupby('name')
df['full_path'] = g['full_path'].transform('last')
df['c_m'] = df['created'].combine_first(df['modified'])
index_cols = ['full_path', 'name']
df = df.pivot_table(index=index_cols,
                    columns='folder',
                    values='c_m',
                    aggfunc='first')
summary_cols = ['created', 'modified']
df = df.reset_index() \
    .merge(g[summary_cols].agg({'created': 'first', 'modified': 'last'}),
           on='name')
df = df[[*index_cols,
         *summary_cols,
         *df.columns.difference(summary_cols + index_cols)]] \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(df)
```

This is the output dataframe:

```
   full_path          name  created modified     T1       T2       T3       T4
C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt 1.txt 14:04:30 14:20:30 14:04:30 14:10:30 14:15:30 14:20:30
```

What I want is for example if the file 1.txt is back to folder T3 then to remove the timestamp in the column T4. So, if i have a dataframe like this:

```
       full_path             name             created           modified
0    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt            14:04:30             NaN
1    C:\T1\1.txt            1.txt              NaN              14:04:30
2    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt            14:10:30              NaN
3    C:\T1\T2\1.txt         1.txt              NaN              14:10:30
4    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt            14:15:30             NaN
5    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt              NaN              14:15:30
6    C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt   1.txt            14:20:30             NaN
7    C:\T1\T2\T3\1.txt      1.txt            14:30:30             NaN
```

I want the output dataframe to be like this:

```
   full_path          name  created modified     T1       T2       T3      T4
C:\T1\T2\T3\T4\1.txt 1.txt 14:04:30 14:20:30 14:04:30 14:10:30 14:30:30   NaN
```

How can I modify the code to have this result? So, the file was in folder T4 and i put a timestamp there but then it moved back to T3 again and I want to remove also the timestamp in T4 because the file is not anymore there.

Comment: Hey @Corralien, for the first question it is working fine for me, what output are you getting? About the second one, if the file is in the folder P8 like you mentioned, there will be a new column added to the df (only P8 not P7). What i want is to track the file position, so as i explanied the file was in T4, but it moved back to T3 and i want that timestamp in T4 to be somehow removed. Maybe the file will be back in T2 in some time, so what i need from the script is to remove the timestamp from T3 and T4. I want this logic in my code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My output is `full_path   name   created  modified       c_m
0  C:\T1\T2\T3\T4.txt  1.txt  14:04:30  14:15:30  14:04:30`

Comment: I edited the question and put the whole code there, can you try that one?

Comment: Same output. I have a `c_m` column instead of `Tn`. Though I copy/paste your code in a fresh session.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Im using pandas 1.2.4

Comment: Same version: 1.2.4